# Vaadin 7.4.9 error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook

Tags: vaadin

I need your help. I want append the external poi library from https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.16-20170419.zip but I get the error. What is bad. Thank for your help! [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For apache poi you need to include the correct jar files, depending which document formats you wish to work with.

[Here](https://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) you see the list of required modules/jars.

For HSSF you will also need the poi-ooxml.jar and poi-ooxml-schemas.jar

Comment: check my post now - the new image. I included the all files. But there is the same problem. I wrote the include to pom.xml too. but that have the same effect. any ideas now ?

Comment: You online need the pom xml. Do a clean/rebuild